# Unable to check required fields with click event

Tags: jquery, html, post, validation

I'm trying to check my input fields for values after a user clicks my form button but it's not  getting into the input loop to check required fields.  Does this not work with a click event? Here is what I'm calling

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(){

    var formValid = true;

    $(".required input").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            $(this).addClass("error_msg");
            formValid = false;
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("error_msg");
        }
    });
    // post form if no errors are seen
```

});

My input HTML looks like this:

```
<input class="required" type="text" value="" name="test" id='test_id' size="80"/>
```

What am I missing?  This seems like it should work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$("input.required")
```

instead of

```
$(".required input")
```

You can submit your form with jQuery [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function:

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(){

    var formValid = true;

    $("input.required").each(function(){
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            $(this).addClass("error_msg");
            formValid = false;
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("error_msg");
        }
    });

    if(formValid) $('#yourForm').submit();
    else return false; //if the button is a submit
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('input.required')` instead.
If you use `$('.required input')`, it will then look for any `input` element, inside the `.required` class. Which in this case, there would be none.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the form submission.